# Alguien sabe porque no me muestra el total de las sumas en mi listbox?

Tags: c#, formularios

Buen día, estoy programando un cotizador para una pequeña empresa, lo ando haciendo con ayuda de C# en forms. Bueno, brevemente, yo tengo una lista de productos en donde se almacenan en un "productos.txt", estos productos los agrego a una lista donde seria como un carrito de compras. El problema viene cuando mi label no esta detectando esta suma de valores. Hice un metodo para lograr esto pero por alguna razon el label se me queda en ceros. Les muestro imagenes a continuación:

[image: Formulario donde se ve que el label de total no se actualiza]

La verdad he estado buscando muchas alternativa y no encuentro cual es el problema con mi codigo y porque no me hace la suma, incluso con ayuda de CHATGPT no he podido encontrar una solución a este problema. No se si sea porque el código esta en un mal orden o que podria ser ya que la verdad aun soy un programador muy novato y este es mi primer "proyecto" seria podriamos decirlo.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Cotizador
{
    public partial class FormCotizador : Form
{

    private Dictionary<string, decimal> productos;

    // Lista de clientes
    private List<Cliente> clientes = new List<Cliente>();

    // Clase que se encarga de los datos del cliente
    public class Cliente
    {
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Telefono { get; set; }
        public string Correo { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Nombre;
        }
    }

    public FormCotizador()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        productos = CargarProductos();
        CargarComboBoxProductos();
    }

    private Dictionary<string, decimal> CargarProductos()
    {
        Dictionary<string, decimal> productos = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
        string[] lineas = File.ReadAllLines("Productos.txt");

        foreach (string linea in lineas)
        {
            string[] datos = linea.Split(',');
            if (datos.Length == 2)
            {
                string nombreProducto = datos[0].Trim();
                decimal precioProducto = decimal.Parse(datos[1].Trim());
                productos.Add(nombreProducto, precioProducto);
            }
        }

        return productos;
    }

    private void CargarComboBoxProductos()
    {
        cmbProducto.DataSource = new BindingSource(productos, null);
        cmbProducto.DisplayMember = "Key"; // Mostrar solo el nombre del producto
        cmbProducto.ValueMember = "Value"; // Mantener el precio como valor
    }

    public void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void cmbClientes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Obtener el cliente seleccionado del ComboBox
        Cliente clienteSeleccionado = (Cliente)cmbClientes.SelectedItem;
    }

    private void FormCotizador_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Cargar productos en el ComboBox de productos
        CargarComboBoxProductos();

        // Cargar clientes en el ComboBox de clientes
        CargarClientesDesdeArchivo();
        MostrarClientesEnComboBox();

        cmbProducto.SelectedIndex = -1; // Deja la ComboBox de productos en blanco
        cmbClientes.SelectedIndex = -1; // Deja la ComboBox de productos en blanco

        lblTotal.Text = "$0.00";
    }

    private void CargarClientesDesdeArchivo()
    {
        try
        {
            string[] lineasClientes = File.ReadAllLines("Clientes.txt");

            foreach (string lineaCliente in lineasClientes)
            {
                string[] datosCliente = lineaCliente.Split(',');

                if (datosCliente.Length == 3)
                {
                    Cliente cliente = new Cliente
                    {
                        Nombre = datosCliente[0],
                        Telefono = datosCliente[1],
                        Correo = datosCliente[2]
                    };

                    clientes.Add(cliente);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("El archivo de clientes no existe.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ocurrió un error al cargar los clientes: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void MostrarClientesEnComboBox()
    {
        cmbClientes.DataSource = null; // Limpiar el DataSource actual
        cmbClientes.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
        cmbClientes.ValueMember = null;
        cmbClientes.DataSource = clientes;
    }

    private void ActualizarTotal()
    {
        decimal total = 0;
        foreach (string item in lstCotizacion.Items)
        {
            // Obtener el precio final del producto en el item de la ListBox
            string[] partes = item.Split('-');
            if (partes.Length >= 2)
            {
                string precioTexto = partes[partes.Length - 1].Trim();
                decimal precio;
                if (decimal.TryParse(precioTexto, out precio))
                {
                    total += precio;
                }
            }
        }

        lblTotal.Text = total.ToString("C");
    }

    private void btnAgregarProducto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string productoSeleccionado = cmbProducto.Text;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productoSeleccionado))
        {
            decimal precioOriginal;
            if (productos.TryGetValue(productoSeleccionado, out precioOriginal))
            {
                decimal ganancia = decimal.Parse(txtAgregarGanancia.Text);
                int cantidad = int.Parse(txtCantidad.Text);
                decimal precioFinal = (precioOriginal + ganancia) * cantidad;


                string itemCotizacion = $"{productoSeleccionado} ({cantidad}) - {precioFinal.ToString("C")}";
                lstCotizacion.Items.Add(itemCotizacion);

                ActualizarTotal();

                txtAgregarGanancia.Text = string.Empty;
                txtCantidad.Text = string.Empty;
                cmbProducto.SelectedIndex = -1; // Dejar la ComboBox de productos en blanco
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se pudo encontrar el precio del producto seleccionado.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }
    }


    private void cmbProducto_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Verificar si se ha seleccionado un ítem en la ListBox
        if (lstCotizacion.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            // Obtener el índice del ítem seleccionado
            int selectedIndex = lstCotizacion.SelectedIndex;

            // Eliminar el ítem seleccionado de la ListBox
            lstCotizacion.Items.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);

            // Actualizar el total
            ActualizarTotal();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Selecciona un producto de la lista para eliminarlo.", "Atención", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }

    private void btnLimpiarLista_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstCotizacion.Items.Clear();

        // Actualizar el total
        ActualizarTotal();
    }

    private void lblTotal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void txtAgregarGanancia_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Le agregue tambien una messagebox para ver que esta pasando y al parecer no es el label, es que simplemente la suma no se esta realizando, ya que lo depure con un messagebox y me sigue saliendo cero

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo haría de otra manera usando un `DataGridView`

**Paso 1: Crear una clase Producto**

```
public class Producto : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Id { init; get; }
    public string Nombre { init; get; } = string.Empty;
    public decimal Precio { init; get; }

    public decimal _cantidad;
    public decimal Cantidad
    {
        get
        {
            return _cantidad;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_cantidad != value)
            {
                _cantidad = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Total");
            }
        }
    }
    public decimal Total => Precio * _cantidad;


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

A la clase `Producto` le agregamos la interfaz `INotifyPropertyChanged` la cual notifica los cambios producidos en alguna propiedad. En nuestro caso a la propiedad `Total`, esto se hace invocando el evento de esta manera `NotifyPropertyChanged("Total");`

Observa que la propiedad `Total` es dependiente de las propiedades `Cantidad` y `Precio` ya que está escrita de esta manera

```
public decimal Total => Precio * _cantidad;
```

Con `INotifyPropertyChanged` avisamos que cada vez que se cambia `Cantidad` también ha habido una modificación en `Total`.

Esto te permitirá editar la cantidad directamente en el DataGridView (por si hubo un error en el cantidad inicial)

**Paso 2: Agregamos los controles**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo agregué

- combobox1: Para la lista de productos
- textbox1: Para la cantidad
- button1: Para agregar el producto
- dataGridView1: Para la cotización
- label1: Para mostrar el total de toda la cotización

**Paso 3: La lógica del asunto**

Tendremos 2 listas

```
public BindingList<Producto> Productos = new BindingList<Producto>();
public BindingList<Producto> Cotizacion = new BindingList<Producto>();
```

La primera `Productos` contiene todos los productos (esta la sacas de tu TXT) y la segunda `Cotizacion` es la que tendrá la cotización

A `Productos` la bindeamos con el `combobox1` y a `Cotizacion` con `dataGridView1`

*Un binding es un enlace, generalmente entre una fuente de datos y un componente visual. El enlace se encarga de mantener sincronizado la fuente de datos (una lista por ejemplo) con el componente, es decir cuando ocurre un cambio en uno afecta al otro*

La lógica será: Cuando agregamos un producto lo sacamos de la lista `Productos` y lo agregamos a la lista `Cotización` de esta manera no habrá productos repetidos.

También agregaremos un botón en la grilla para quitar los productos, el cual hará lo contrario, quitará de "Cotización" y lo volverá a agregar en `Productos`

**El código del Form**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public BindingList<Producto> Productos = new BindingList<Producto>();
    public BindingList<Producto> Cotizacion = new BindingList<Producto>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //datos de ejemplo tu los sacas de tu TXT
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Productos.Add(new Producto()
            {
                Id = i,
                Nombre = "Producto " + i,
                Precio = i * 1000
            });
        }
        comboBox1.DataSource = Productos;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Nombre";

        Cotizacion.ListChanged += UpdateCotizacion;

        //Quitamos el agregar y borrar filas que tiene el datagridview, porque nosotros crearemos un sistema propio
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 54;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = Cotizacion;

        //seteamos que algunas columnas no se puedan editar, permitiendo que solo se edite la columna de cantidad
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].ReadOnly = false;


        //Agregamos un botón para eliminar
        DataGridViewButtonColumn button = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        button.Name = "Quitar";
        button.HeaderText = "";
        button.Text = "Quitar";
        button.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(button);

        //agregamos un evento para detectar cuando se presiona el botón "quitar"
        dataGridView1.CellContentClick += DataGridView1_CellContentClick1;

    }

    //Boton Quitar
    private void DataGridView1_CellContentClick1(object? sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender!;
        var producto = senderGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as Producto;
        var button = senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewButtonColumn;
        if (button is not null || producto is not null)
        {
            Cotizacion.Remove(producto); //removemos de la cotizacion

            //limpiamos el producto
            producto.PropertyChanged -= UpdateCotizacion; //quitamos el evento
            producto.Cantidad = 0; //seteamos la cantidad en cero

            //lo volvemos a agregear a la lista de productos
            Productos.Add(producto);
        }
           

    }

    //cada vez que se actualiza la lista o la propiedad Cantidad se actualiza el TOTAL de la cotización
    private void UpdateCotizacion(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = Cotizacion.Sum(a => a.Total).ToString();
    }


    //boton agregar
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int cantidad;
        if(int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out cantidad)) //verificamos que la cantidad sea int
        {
            Producto producto = comboBox1.SelectedItem as Producto;
            producto.Cantidad = cantidad; 
            producto.PropertyChanged += UpdateCotizacion; //agregamos un evento para actualizar el TOTAL
            Productos.Remove(producto); //sacamos de la lista productos
            Cotizacion.Add(producto); //agregamos a la cotización
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        }
        
    }
}
```

**Resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]